# Postgres - slow timestamp query with <1 mln rows index

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a table "ads" which has 300k rows and timestamptz field created_dttm.

I also created an index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ads_created_dttm ON public.ads USING btree (created_dttm DESC)
```

Postgres 11.5

Hardware:

AWS RDS db.t3.micro instance with 1Gb of RAM.

Settings:

work_mem = 4mb

shared_buffers = 200mb

Query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select *
from ads
where created_dttm > now() - INTERVAL '7 days'
```

Result:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on ads  (cost=2384.70..85812.93 rows=70229 width=1168) (actual time=277.807..15271.938 rows=69655 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
  Heap Blocks: exact=28138
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ads_created_dttm  (cost=0.00..2367.14 rows=70229 width=0) (actual time=273.162..273.163 rows=71134 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
Planning Time: 0.193 ms
Execution Time: 15294.303 ms
```

How can I reduce those 15 seconds? I have standard work_mem = 4MB. Tried to increase - found no profit.

UPD:
Currently, last 7 days are 20% of total rows, so without the index it works faster (but still not enough).

```
Seq Scan on ads  (cost=0.00..54661.36 rows=69983 width=1171) (actual time=0.560..5289.579 rows=69681 loops=1)
  Filter: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 239368
Planning Time: 2.611 ms
Execution Time: 5306.566 ms
```

And with the time 7 days will go below 5% of all rows, so index will be worth it.

UPD2: 
and today postgres doesn't use index at all

```
Seq Scan on ads  (cost=0.00..87967.99 rows=80355 width=1171) (actual time=0.610..9587.440 rows=71120 loops=1)
  Filter: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 247419
  Buffers: shared hit=16393 read=65283
  I/O Timings: read=9231.171
Planning Time: 0.142 ms
Execution Time: 9604.402 ms
```

UPD3:
without DESC in index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ads_created_dttm ON public.ads USING btree (created_dttm)

Bitmap Heap Scan on ads  (cost=1335.58..84997.06 rows=71117 width=1171) (actual time=63.478..8286.637 rows=71172 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
  Heap Blocks: exact=28901
  Buffers: shared hit=9033 read=20065 written=16
  I/O Timings: read=7473.119 write=0.168
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ads_created_dttm  (cost=0.00..1317.80 rows=71117 width=0) (actual time=58.612..58.612 rows=71172 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
        Buffers: shared hit=34 read=163
        I/O Timings: read=48.280
Planning Time: 4.994 ms
Execution Time: 8305.113 ms
```

UPD4:
Probably I was wrong by asking the question. 
My original query - I search for average ads per day (last week) for particular search filters.

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.duplicates_url IS NULL THEN a.url ELSE a.duplicates_url END) /7
FROM ads a
  LEFT JOIN metro_lines ml ON a.metro_stations && ml.stations
WHERE (a.bedroom_num = ANY (ARRAY [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) OR (5 = ANY (ARRAY [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) AND a.bedroom_num >= 5) OR
       (ARRAY [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] IS NULL)) AND
      (a.price BETWEEN 1000 AND 200000 OR 1000 IS NULL AND 200000 IS NULL OR a.price >= 1000 AND 200000 IS NULL OR
       a.price <= 200000 AND 1000 IS NULL) AND (
        ARRAY ['1.135', '1.152', '5.20', '2.19'] :: VARCHAR [] && a.metro_stations OR
        (ARRAY ['1.135', '1.152', '5.20', '2.19'] :: VARCHAR [] IS NULL AND 0 IS NULL AND NULL :: VARCHAR [] IS NULL) OR
        ((0 IS NOT NULL OR NULL :: VARCHAR [] IS NOT NULL) AND ((a.metro_circle_distance <= 0 OR 0 IS NULL) AND
                                                                (ml.line_id = ANY (NULL :: VARCHAR []) OR
                                                                 NULL :: VARCHAR [] IS NULL)))) AND
      (5 IS NULL OR ('f' = 't' AND a.metro_distance_type = 'f') OR
       'f' = a.metro_distance_type AND a.metro_distance_time <= 5) AND a.created_dttm > NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
```

Result:

```
Aggregate  (cost=82281.61..82281.62 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6143.042..6143.043 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=5754 read=13165
  I/O Timings: read=5671.779
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=10100.72..82253.18 rows=11371 width=81) (actual time=2138.635..6081.796 rows=6547 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (a.metro_stations && ml.stations)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 81773
        Buffers: shared hit=5754 read=13165
        I/O Timings: read=5671.779
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ads a  (cost=10100.72..65183.38 rows=4738 width=114) (actual time=2138.569..5987.932 rows=4416 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval)) AND (metro_distance_time <= 5))
              Filter: ((price >= 1000) AND (price <= 200000) AND ('f'::bpchar = metro_distance_type) AND (('{1.135,1.152,5.20,2.19}'::character varying[] && metro_stations) OR (metro_circle_distance <= 0)) AND ((bedroom_num = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[])) OR (bedroom_num >= 5)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 21449
              Heap Blocks: exact=16662
              Buffers: shared hit=5753 read=13165
              I/O Timings: read=5671.779
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=10100.72..10100.72 rows=25623 width=0) (actual time=2134.204..2134.204 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=189 read=2067
                    I/O Timings: read=2080.070
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ads_created_dttm  (cost=0.00..1322.63 rows=71227 width=0) (actual time=16.304..16.304 rows=71300 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (created_dttm > (now() - '7 days'::interval))
                          Buffers: shared hit=179 read=18
                          I/O Timings: read=3.769
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ads_metro_distance_time  (cost=0.00..8775.47 rows=114540 width=0) (actual time=2115.495..2115.495 rows=117618 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (metro_distance_time <= 5)
                          Buffers: shared hit=10 read=2049
                          I/O Timings: read=2076.300
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..13.60 rows=240 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.005 rows=20 loops=4416)
              Buffers: shared hit=1
              ->  Seq Scan on metro_lines ml  (cost=0.00..12.40 rows=240 width=32) (actual time=0.019..0.027 rows=20 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 1.481 ms
Execution Time: 6143.911 ms
```

I tried to find out the reason, why it is that slow. As far as I understood its because of the timestamp filter. Am I wrong?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: What is your hardware like?  The worst hardware I have readily available does better than this from a cold start, and much better than this with a warm cache.

Comment: @jjanes I added the info

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: how fast does it work without index?

Comment: In theory it shouldn't matter, but what if you create the index without the DESC?

Comment: @Nikita in the last update it doesn't use index - you can see results

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name now it uses the index again but still slow

Comment: you need to return a lot of rows, so server needs to make a lot of key lookups or read the whole table (depending on estimations it can choose one of these plans) Of course you can create covered index with all columns to avoid key lookups and reduce scan time in five times but the question is - why do you need to return 80K of rows in one query?

Comment: @Nikita I added my original query

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve completely different task than you described in the beginning. No, it works slow not just because of the timestamp filter. Your query contains a lot of other filters and depending on their combinations and parameters values server may choose different execution plans.

Comment: I would say it's your hardware (disks, I/O). If you take the I/O timings and number of blocks retrieved, this results in a throughput of about 20-25MB per second.